# Set cookie expiration to 2 minutes for yourls

Tags: php, cookies, open-source, bit.ly, yourls

I am new to [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) and just set it up on [nmdrp.me](http://nmdrp.me) to be able to forward to my site, [namedrop.io](https://namedrop.io). For e.g. [nmdrp.me/1](http://nmdrp.me/1).

The challenge I am trying to solve is that once I go to [nmdrp.me/1](http://nmdrp.me/1) on my Chrome browser the first time, the Counter for the page goes +1. But then when I got to [nmdrp.me/1](http://nmdrp.me/1) again after that from the same browser (no matter how many minutes later), the counter doesn't go up.

[Bit.ly](http://bit.ly) is able to pick up the next visit to the site from the same browser after 2 minutes.

I believe this is because there is a cookie set to not expire by default on nmdrp.me - and I want to change that.

Can you please tell me how to change the cookie.php to be able to set cookies that expire in 2 minutes, so I can also pick up the next visit on the same browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with cookies - http://nmdrp.me/1 serves a 301 redirect. 301 redirects (being "permanent") are cached by the browser - subsequent visits to the same URL will be served from the cache rather than your server, meaning no more cicks counted.

There are [a few places in the codebase](https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=yourls_redirect&type=Code) you'll need to change if you want this adjusted.

**edit:** Bit.ly uses a header, `Cache-Control: private, max-age=90`, to address this with their 301s to limit the cache to 90 seconds.

Comment: So is Bit.ly using 302 redirects? I was reading that's not recommended because with 302 you don't get link attribution credit.

Is there no other way? Clear the cache for nmdrp.me host?

Comment: @credizian Bit.ly appears to send `Cache-Control: private, max-age=90` with their 301 redirects to fix this, which you could try as well.

Comment: would you know where I would indicate this in the code?

Comment: @credizian Adjust the `yourls_redirect` function. You'll need to add another `header()` call in there.

Comment: will try this out. Not sure how to yet, but I understand what you asked me to do. :) Ty!

Comment: Old thread but, for posterity, I just want to state that there are several YOURLS plugins available to deal with this. *Never* "adjust" functions (ie edit core code) if you can have a separate plugin do the desired task.